# How to upload a image file from loacal system at Runtime using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

how to upload a image file at run time which is available in local system using jmeter

Use case: in my application we need to upload a image which is avilable in loacal system.

Answer (score 0):

Update the file path and other details in the HTTP request.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the following fields of the [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

- Tick `Use multipartform-data for POST` checkbox
- Provide values in `Send Files With the Request` section for

  - File Path (it is recommended to use full paths where possible)
  - Mime Type
  - Parameter Name

For more information on how to perform file upload and download operations using JMeter see [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide.